# VBA to Download, Extract and Import Zip File to Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a simple link, www.example.com/file.zip.  It's a public server and requires no login.

The link is to a zip file.  The zip file contains a tab-delimited text file (20MB).

Is there an all-in-one code to download the zip file to a temp folder...extract the text file...and import its data to an Excel worksheet?

Each run of the macro would overwrite the previous data with new data.

I tried to apply the solution from another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486871/how-to-import-a-zipped-csv-hosted-online-into-excel), but I can't get it to work.  The answer to the other post involved unzipping a csv file and saving it as a text file.  My zipped file already contains a text file.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import a zipped csv hosted online into Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486871/how-to-import-a-zipped-csv-hosted-online-into-excel)

Comment: You may want to check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35757699/excel-vba-read-txt-from-zip-files/35781621#35781621

Comment: Thanks for referring me to those posts.  However, I can't get those scripts to work.  I asked a question in the post but it didn't contribute and was deleted.

Comment: I can't get those scripts to work. means nothing to anyone as you are the only one who knows what is not happening.   Post code....we are not a code writing service.

Comment: I understand.  You're right, I was dependent on a code writing service.  Thanks.

Comment: ...and I am trying to pay-it-forward by answering questions about Excel formulas...because, in here, that's all I know.